# Test dgram binding in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

How can I write a test to verify that my application is binding to a particular UDP port via dgram? Below is a snippet of the code I am wanting to test:

```
var dgram         = require('dgram');
var socket_json   = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var socket_syslog = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket_json.bind(6371);
socket_syslog.bind(6370);
```

I am attempting to use Mocha and Chai for my tests:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var sawyer = require("../server.js");

describe("Sawyer", function() {
    it("should bind to UDP port 6370", function() {
        // some kind of expect statement here
    });

    it("should bind to UDP port 6371", function() {
        // some kind of expect statement here
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_bind_port_address_callback), an `error` event will be emitted on `socket` or an error could be thrown if the `socket.bind()` fails.

So you could watch for those two things and also add a callback argument to `socket.bind()` (or add a `listening` event handler on `socket`, which is what `socket.bind()` does for you), which is called once the binding is complete.

Example:

```
socket_json.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Socket error: ' + err.message);
}).on('listening', function() {
  console.log('Successfully bound JSON socket!');
});
try {
  socket_json.bind(6371);
} catch (ex) {
  console.log('Failed to bind JSON socket: ' + ex.message);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should just test what's written to console.log() instead of testing the binding directly?

Comment: No, that's merely just filler. It's up to you how you want to handle errors such that you can check for them in your unit tests. One option might be to catch thrown errors and emit them instead via `socket_json.emit('error', ex)` so that you only have to listen for two events, `error` for errors and `listening` for success. In your unit tests, you could listen for these two events (unless you want some other kind of interface, again it's up to you).